# Cant connect to google cloud SQL from Compute Engine Instance

Tags: laravel, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have a Laravel application running on Google Compute Engine instance. I have configured it to connect to a Cloud SQL database Instance, when I SSH to the VM and run `php artisan migrate` everything runs smoothly. But when I open the application in a browser I get this Error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Permission denied` I cant figure out what is going wrong here, I have tried cloud sql proxy but still the application cant establish a DB connection when accessed from a browser. Can anyone figure out the cause of this weird behavior.

Comment: Can you provide any more logs? `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Permission denied` Can be caused by a number of factors. My guess goes to selinux. Try disabling it. If it works while disabled, re enable it and perform the following command on your laravel instance. `sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db=1`

Comment: Seems the problem was selinux was preventing the web server from connecting the to the remote database. enabling httpd_can_network_connect_db fixes the issue. Thanks @IlyasDeckers for pointing out that.

Comment: To help to the community please post it as an answer as the issue fixed by enabling 'httpd_can_network_connect_db'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by enabling httpd_can_network_connect_db flag in selinux by running this command.

`sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db=1`

I also faced another issue with SELinux with redis and solved it by running this command.

`sudo semanage port -m -t http_port_t -p tcp 6379`